# Custom search form

Tags: html, drupal, customization

I am currently printing the search from like this:

```
$block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
print render($block);
```

Which generates:

```
<form action="/sescam/" method="post" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <div class="container-inline">
             <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>

            <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
                <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search</label>
                <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
                <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-NhLKDp33kDMoJjHqw6gDFJw_A_Kp7Dhvrt_w0V-jk6U" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="e9aNbw3gz2mWvZUSdjl54aXTlesQsNkn7cGSXVMpoWI" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The thing is that I would like to customize a little bit this html output.

How can I do so?

-EDIT-

I tried to add this to my template.php

```
function my_theme_form_search_form_alter (& $form, & $form_state)
{
  print_r($form);
  print_r($form_state);
}
```

The thing is that those `print_r` won't output anything,

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_search_blok_form.
 */
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_search_block_form(&$variables) {

  var_dump($variables,'vars');

  // do your thing

}
```

or

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {

    dpm($form,'form'); // install devel module for dpm() function

    // do your thing

  }
}
```